# How to hyphenate caption in subfigure?

Tags: subfloats

I have a centered subfigure with 2 images with 2 caption like so

[image: figures]

they are made with the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
      \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{04 Introduction/figurer/Quiescent_galaxies_allz_UVJ_classic.png}
          \caption{Quiescent galaxies in UVJ colors from the Classic catalog plotted against redshift in bins of approximately 2 billion years.}
          \label{fig:cq_uvj}
      \end{subfigure}
      \hfill
      \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{04 Introduction/figurer/Quiescent_galaxies_allz_UVJ_farmer.png}
          \centering\caption{\hspace{0pt} Quiescent galaxies in UVJ colors from the Farmer catalog plotted against redshift in bins of approximately 2 billion years.}
          \label{fig:fq_uvj}
      \end{subfigure}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:cfq_uvj}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}
```

However, the caption for each image is not hyphenated. How can I split up the words so they align nicely?

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.  (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) If I guess what would be needed to make the code compilable, I end up with a different output.

Comment: Would you like the subfigures' captions (a) centered line by line, (b) fully justified, or (c) ragged-right? (Of course, in all three cases you'd also want to permit hyphenation.) Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I would prefer the caption ragged right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the `ragged2e` package, the option `justfication=RaggedRight` (note the two uppercase-R letters) becomes available to `\captionsetup`. The difference between `justfication=RaggedRight` and `justfication=raggedright` is that the former allows hyphenation of the caption text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,ragged2e}
% abandon full justification of caption text, but allow hyphenation:
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=RaggedRight} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{04 Introduction/figurer/Quiescent_galaxies_allz_UVJ_classic.png}
  \caption{Quiescent galaxies in UVJ colors from the Classic catalogue, plotted against redshift in bins of approximately 2 billion years.}
  \label{fig:cq_uvj}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{04 Introduction/figurer/Quiescent_galaxies_allz_UVJ_farmer.png}
  \caption{Quiescent galaxies in UVJ colors from the Farmer catalogue, plotted against redshift in bins of approximately 2 billion years.}
  \label{fig:fq_uvj}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{fig:cfq_uvj}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this helped and now my captions are hyphenated

Answer (score 2):

- Please always (if possible) provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which reproduce your problem.
- Your code fragment is strange. Don't use `center` environment (which introduce additional vertical space), rather use command `\centering`.
- Don't insert formatting into caption.

**Edit:**
As you say in comment, source of your problem is settings `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`. This not a part od code fragment in question  Apparently you need separate settings for `subfigure`. Now both added to the following MWE gives what you ask:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[justification=justified]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Quiescent galaxies in UVJ colors from the Classic catalog plotted against redshift in bins of approximately 2 billion years.}
\label{fig:cq_uvj}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Quiescent galaxies in UVJ colors from the Farmer catalog plotted against red shift in bins of approximately 2 billion years.}
\label{fig:fq_uvj}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{my figure}
    \label{fig:cfq_uvj}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried updating my question, however I use a lot of packages to load the document. It would probably take up too much space here. 
I tried to implement your MWE, but the caption does still not hyphenate

Comment: @CecilieHansen, my MWE for sure works as it is. Apparently in your preamble is some settings, which cause your problem.  Since we don't know, what is yin your preamble, the source you need to find yourself. Prepare own MWE, which reproduce your problem. As starting point can serve ma answer. SO far your code fragment can not be compiled.

Comment: yes, i I found the reason why it didn't work for me, I was using `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`  where i instead should have used the `\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=RaggedRight}` like @Mico wrote.